# Можно ли настроить порядок подключения неймспейсов в PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains, namespace

В проекте есть папки с классами:

- entities
- models
- services
- controllers
- components
- modules
- и т.д.

Сейчас *PhpStorm* может упорядочить только по алфавиту, но меня это не совсем устраивает. Не важно почему.

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике ReformatCode или RefactorCode или при Auto Import'е неймспейса был всегда определённый порядок и *PhpStorm* делал бы это за меня. Можно ли это где-то настроить? Например сделать порядок такой же, как в списке выше?

Comment: Напишите в техподдержку, а потом сами дайте ответ. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new